# Identifying the domains implemented in Firefox RDP which is subset of the Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, firefox-developer-tools

Firefox implements the Remote Debugging Protocol (RDP), which is a subset of the Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP). You can find detailed information about RDP in the [official documentation](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/remote/cdp/).

Some methods like [`Page.navigate`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Page/#method-navigate) work, enabling basic browser automation with Puppeteer. However, some methods like [`Schema.getDomains`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Schema/) do not work in Firefox.

If you want to find out which domains are implemented in Firefox, where should you look for this information?